# Azure Table Storage SAS REST

Tags: rest, azure

I've been using azure's table storage using REST for some time now. Last time i implemented it it was easy. I just generated a SAS URI using azures tool, but now when i do the same thing i get this error

```
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<code>AuthenticationFailed</code>
<message xml:lang="en-US">
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:7792095b-0002-0084-1f67-0c06e6000000 Time:2017-08-03T14:47:23.3575632Z
</message>
</error>
```

What has change and how can i acces my tables again ?

Comment: Have you provided a StartTime for the SAS? This can happen due to clock drift between the client machine where you might have generated the SAS and the authenticating server. 
Check this blog for a probable solution - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kwill/2013/08/27/http-403-server-failed-to-authenticate-the-request-when-using-shared-access-signatures/

Answer (score 0):

i found an answer. Just use Azure Storage Explorer to generate the SAS